# Printing text with different font sizes on the same page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to determine how I would utilize a generic list to print out text with various size fonts.
I know I would have to loop through the list to send the object to the

```
Graphics.DrawString(String, Font, Brush, PointF)
```

method.

I'm just having trouble as how to set the objects in the list so I can loop through and print them.

I have a class(PrintString) that takes a string and a font as its constructor, then a list inside my print class that I set:

```
public List<PrintString> ps = new List<PrintString>();
```

I have no problem populating the list from my form:

```
ReceiptPrint receipt = new ReceiptPrint();
receipt.ps.Add(new PrintString(printHead,new Font("Arial", 20)));
receipt.ps.Add(new PrintString(dateTime, new Font("Arial", 14)));
receipt.Print();
```

The place where I'm getting stuck is inside my print class (ReceiptPrint) where I am trying to iterate through the list to pass the string and font to the DrawString method.

```
foreach (PrintString printString in ps)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ps??????????
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a matter of passing the string and font I set in my PrintString class:

```
foreach (PrintString printString in ps)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(printString.Text, printString.Font, Brushes.Black, printArea, format);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with members for anything unique to the particular item, such as Text, Font Size, and Location.

Then create instances of this class and add them to a new List<YourClassType>;

Finally, iterate over the list and draw the items.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure how I would pass the list to my print class.

Comment: You should just be able to have your function accept List<YourClassType> as a parameter.

Comment: How can I get the DrawString method to accept the list as a parameter? I have a generic list generated in my print class that accepts a string and font. Now I don't how to pass that on in a loop.